# How to reuse the redis connection?

Tags: rust, redis

I am trying to connect to redis. This is what my code looks like:

```
#[get("/v1.1/playlist/detail/<req_playlist_id>")]
pub async fn playlist_detail_attr(req_playlist_id: i64, loginUserInfo: LoginUserInfo) -> content::Json<String> {
    let playlistKey = "music:playlist:";
    let keyResult = format!("{}{}", playlistKey, loginUserInfo.userId);
    const REDIS_CON_STRING: &str = "redis://AoGTmVy3U7@cruise-redis-master.reddwarf-cache.svc.cluster.local:6379";
    let redis_client = redis::Client::open(REDIS_CON_STRING).expect("can create redis client");
    let mut redis_conn = get_con(redis_client);
    let cached_playlist = get_str(&mut redis_conn.as_ref().unwrap(), &keyResult).await;
    return if cached_playlist.as_ref().unwrap().is_empty() {
        let playlistDetail = query_playlist_detail(req_playlist_id).await;
        let res = ApiResponse {
            result: playlistDetail,
            ..Default::default()
        };
        let response_json = serde_json::to_string(&res).unwrap();
        set_str(&mut redis_conn.unwrap(), &keyResult, &response_json, 60*60*24*7);
        content::Json(response_json)
    } else {
        content::Json(cached_playlist.unwrap())
    }
}
```

I want to reuse the `redis_conn` in the query redis operation and set redis operation if the cached key is null. When I compile this code it shows an error:

```
error[E0596]: cannot borrow data in a `&` reference as mutable
  --> src/biz/music/playlist_controller.rs:21:35
   |
21 |     let cached_playlist = get_str(&mut redis_conn.as_ref().unwrap(), &keyResult).await;
   |                                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ cannot borrow as mutable
```

Comment: Its not clear what type `redis_conn` is, but if its an `Option` or `Result`, perhaps you want `.as_mut()` instead of `.as_ref()`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think `as_ref()` or `as_mut()` is necessary as you have specified a mutable borrow, with `&mut`, to `redis_conn` when passing it as parameter to the function `get_str`. Also, adding `unwrap()` to the end of `get_con` will save the calls of 'unwrap()' against redis_conn in the places where redis_conn is used. That said, the changes are like below. Give it a try.

```
let mut redis_conn = get_con(redis_client).unwrap();
let cached_playlist = get_str(&mut redis_conn, &keyResult).await;
```